# Mysql 5.6.12 Group_concat with Inner Join Issue

Tags: mysql, inner-join, mysql-error-1064, group-concat

Earlier we used to use Mysql Version 5.5.27 and with the following query

```
 SELECT S.StudentId, 
        SED.StudentEnrollmentDetailsId,
        FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, PermanentAddress,
        GROUP_CONCAT(B.BatchName ORDER BY B.BatchId,B.IsVirtualBatch DESC) AS AllBatch  
 FROM Student S 
 INNER JOIN StudentEnrollmentDetails SED ON SED.StudentId = S.StudentId
 INNER JOIN StudentBatchTxn SBT ON SBT.StudentId = S.StudentId  
 WHERE SED.StudentId = ?
 AND SED.StudentEnrollmentDetailsId = ? AND S.CompanyId = ?
```

This query use to run properly whether student is present in StudentBatchTxn or not.

But now we have upgraded to mysql 5.6.12. Same query is returning rows with all columns as null.

Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below link should be helpful

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bugs.html

Comment: @Amar or user2298894 could you please elaborate what part of this link is relevant to the question. Please quote the part of the content which explains this problem (you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17548303/edit) the answer). (Link-only answers are strongly discouraged)

Answer (score 2):

Did that really work in 5.5.27?

- INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables

Can you change the INNER JOIN's in LEFT JOIN's

- LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table

Comment: It did work, Even I am amazed. Now to Change so many in production is going to be very heavy task and time consuming.

Comment: Perhaps the old version stripped the `INNER JOIN StudentBatchTxn` because you don't have fields in the select. But according to the SQL standard the INNER JOIN should only result in records with entries in BOTH tables. (so its fixed in the latest version:)